# Can you make 128 bit unsigned ints in Arduino (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am using uints to store bit sequences and would like to store a bit sequence of 128. I plan to cycle through them using a circular bit rotation. Is there a nice way to make a 128 bit integer? If not, what is the next best thing that can easily be "circular bit shifted"?

I need this to run quickly because it will be happening in an interrupt. About every 250 microseconds.

Comment: `Can you make 128-bit ints?` Yes. `Can you make it fast?` Depends on the CPU

Comment: @EvanCarslake `__int128` is only supported on 64-bit platforms, which Arduino is not

Comment: Do you really need to cycle the number? Can't you just memorize the index position and use 4 uint32_ts?

Comment: I wrote an answer... but on the other hand, leaving the data in place and rotating the read/write position *is* probably a much smarter idea than rotating the data.

Comment: @hobbs I want to circularly shift the bits instead of referring to the index because it is less operations per interrupt. With circular rotating it is only one shift operation every interrupt. Whereas, the other method requires n shifts where n is the index you want to reach. Isn't circular a lot faster?

Comment: @Blue0ak no. The AVR is an 8-bit processor, so you can't rotate 128 bits in anything less than 16 shifts (and my code, which may or may not be optimal, takes 85 instructions, many of them 2-cycle ones). But referring to the index could be done in 0 shifts and many fewer instructions if you don't mind spending 8 bytes of RAM on a lookup table.

Comment: @hobbs I can definitely use 8-bits of RAM on that. Would I write the method that uses this lookup table in assembly? I am not familiar with how to actual implement assembly code, any good resources?

Comment: @Blue0ak I think it would be possible to do it in C without any loss in efficiency — another advantage.

Comment: @hobbs How do you refer to specific bits in the int? Would you just have a global variable of the number of shifts and shift over that many times each interrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `char[16]` array, and write the critical shifting code in assembly, rather than C, because C doesn't have a good way to give you access to the carry-out from a shift.

You should be able to do something like

```
ldi r29, hi8(array) ; Load Y register
ldi r28, lo8(array) ; (16 bits)
ldi r22, 16         ; Loop counter
ldd r23, Y+15       ; Get the last byte
lsl r23             ; And put the last bit into the carry flag
loop:               ;   so it will be shifted into the first bit
ld r23, Y           ; Load from array into r23
rol                 ; Rotate left through carry
st Y+, r23          ; Store it back and increment Y
dec r22             ; Decrement loop counter
brne loop           ; Loop if not done
```

to do the rotation, but this is untested and I'm not an AVR assembly whiz. `dec` is special and doesn't interfere with the carry flag, so it's preserved safely through the loop.